# Docker build fails when outside of profile folder

Tags: docker

I can't work out why Docker fails do build an image when outside of a user's profile directory.

`unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/lib/snapd/void/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem. I've done this in a sudo session to rule out any permission issues.

Working example:

```
chuck@ubuntu20lts:~$ sudo -s
root@ubuntu20lts:/home/chuck# cd ~
root@ubuntu20lts:~# mkdir test
root@ubuntu20lts:~# echo FROM nginx:latest > ~/test/Dockerfile
root@ubuntu20lts:~# cd test
root@ubuntu20lts:~/test# cat Dockerfile
FROM nginx:latest
root@ubuntu20lts:~/test# docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/1 : FROM nginx:latest
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
a330b6cecb98: Pull complete
5ef80e6f29b5: Pull complete
f699b0db74e3: Pull complete
0f701a34c55e: Pull complete
3229dce7b89c: Pull complete
ddb78cb2d047: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:a05b0cdd4fc1be3b224ba9662ebdf98fe44c09c0c9215b45f84344c12867002e
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
 ---> 822b7ec2aaf2
Successfully built 822b7ec2aaf2
root@ubuntu20lts:~/test#
```

Trying the same thing in a different folder fails:

```
root@ubuntu20lts:~/test# mkdir /test
root@ubuntu20lts:~/test# echo FROM nginx:latest > /test/Dockerfile
root@ubuntu20lts:~/test# cd /test
root@ubuntu20lts:/test# cat Dockerfile
FROM nginx:latest
root@ubuntu20lts:/test# docker build .
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/lib/snapd/void/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
root@ubuntu20lts:/test#
```

In case it matters, I'm using Ubuntu 20 LTS in Virtual Box on a W10 host.

Comment: The slightly weird message usually means cannot find Dockerfile in the directory you are running docker build from. Is the log you pasted above definitely correct i.e. it is definitely called Dockerfile and not accidentally DockerFile or something non-standard? Have you tried specifying it with -f to see if that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason found. The Snap package seems to be cause. Whether it's a bug or a feature, who knows?

**Solution: Uninstall the Snap package and install the Apt package.**

```
root@ubuntu20lts:/test# sudo snap remove docker
docker removed
root@ubuntu20lts:/test# docker

Command 'docker' not found, but can be installed with:

snap install docker     # version 20.10.8, or
apt  install docker.io  # version 20.10.7-0ubuntu1~20.04.1

See 'snap info docker' for additional versions.
root@ubuntu20lts:/test# apt install docker.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
...
...
root@ubuntu20lts:/test# docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu1~20.04.1
root@ubuntu20lts:/test# docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/1 : FROM nginx:latest
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
a330b6cecb98: Pull complete
5ef80e6f29b5: Pull complete
f699b0db74e3: Pull complete
0f701a34c55e: Pull complete
3229dce7b89c: Pull complete
ddb78cb2d047: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:a05b0cdd4fc1be3b224ba9662ebdf98fe44c09c0c9215b45f84344c12867002e
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
 ---> 822b7ec2aaf2
Successfully built 822b7ec2aaf2
root@ubuntu20lts:/test#
```